# Swift, use UIViewController as LaunchScreen

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to use my main `UIViewController` as `LaunchScreen` 
Is there any way ?

Cus i have autoLayout and when i want to copy all my objects autoLayout not works well

**(Or Just Set My Main `UIViewController` as startup screen / launch screen)**

*Thanks*,

Answer (score -1):

Just set your ViewController as the initial view controller in storyboard.